# Почему DNS пакеты уходят напрямую на DNS сервер? Wireshark

Tags: dns, tcp-ip, wireshark

В Wireshark посмотрел структуру DNS пакета. Там в MAC-адресе пункта назначения указан адрес шлюза по умолчанию, но в IP-адресе назначения указан IP DNS сервера. Хотя во многих статьях об устройстве пакетов DNS я встречал, что там указан IP шлюза по умолчанию, а не DNS сервера. От чего это зависит и почему так?

Comment: Можно пример такой статьи?

Comment: @andreymal https://russianblogs.com/article/3927228890/

Comment: Статья выглядит безграмотной, скорее всего на маршрутизаторе просто установлен свой маленький DNS-сервер, то есть пакеты точно так же уходят напрямую на DNS-сервер, а автор статьи не смог этого понять

Comment: @andreymal собственно, если подводить итог. В пакете DNS в поле пункта назначения всегда указан конечная точка всего маршрута - DNS Сервер, а в поле MAC-адреса пункта назначения - следующая точка в пути (в данном случае адрес роутера)? И в статье, получается, DNS Сервером является сам шлюз по умолчанию?

Comment: Да. Практически все домашние роутеры являются (кэширующими) dns серверами и анонсируют по DHCP себя в качестве DNS сервера. (При дефолтных настройках)